# Text not allowed in element select in this context

Tags: php, html, validation

I created a forum, where students have to fill out their year of graduation. When I was validating my file, as shown by the comment, the line below produces an error, "Text not allowed in element `select` in this context." I need to name "year" in the select tag, so I can use the post array to get the year. How can I fix this validation error?

```
<form method="post">
    <div class = "mailInput"> 
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"> 
            <span class="error"> <?php echo $nameErr;?></span></div>
    <div class = "mailInput">
        Email: <input type="text" name="email"> 
            <span class="error"> <?php echo $emailErr;?></span> </div>
    <div class = "mailInput">
        Major: <input type="text" name="major"> 
            <span class="error"> <?php echo $majorErr;?></span> </div>
    <div class = "mailInput">
        Year: <select class="select" name="year"> // this line produces an error
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
            <option value="2018">2018</option>
            <option value="2019">2019</option>
            <option value="2020">2020</option>
        </select> 
    </div>
    <div class = "mailInput lastInput"> Gender:  
         <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female
         <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male
    </div>
    <span class="error"> <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
    <div class = "submitButton"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Join">
    </div>
    <div class="message"> <?php echo $submitMessage;?></div>
</form>
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST["year"])) {
        $year = $_POST["year"];
    }
}
```

Comment: have you placed your php code after `<?php`.every thing else looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`// this line produces an error` will prevent your code from working as it is not the correct way to write comments in HTML code.

The correct way is by using `<!-- -->` and therefore, in your case, it should have been `<!-- this line produces an error -->`

`//` is used to write comments in PHP and JavaScript.

`/* */` is used to write comments in CSS.

Comment: @15ongm What is `!empty($_POST['submit']` for? A submit button cannot be empty.

Comment: ohh i meant that it was not empty (aka the submit button was click)... okay i'll delete that

Comment: @15ongm Any chance you could link me to the site?

Comment: oh nvm fixed it! I had `// this line produces an error` actually in my code and it didn't register as a comment

Comment: @15ongm Brilliant

Comment: @15ongm `<!-- text here -->` is the correct way to comment. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @15ongm Updated